# VLOOKUP doesn't work with complicated URL as cell content

Tags: excel, url, vlookup

I have the following situation.

I use the function VLOOKUP in Sheet2, using a table array from Sheet1:

```
=VLOOKUP(A4,Sheet1!$A$2:$B$81,2,FALSE)
```

I am comparing URLs written in cells formatted as "text".

I basically try to mass replace some URLs with others.

When the URL is a simple one, such as the one below, the formula works fine.

`http://www.website.com/page/` that becomes `http://www.website.com/newpage/`

The formula works fine and returns `http://www.website.com/newpage/` in the range cell

When the URL is a complicated one, such as the one below, the formula returns `#VALUE!`

```
http://www.website.com/configurator/?dimensiuni%5B%5D=100&toate-categoriile=1&orice-duritate=1&toti-producatorii=1&orice-buget=1&toate_236=1&toate_234=1&toate_235=1&toate_237=1&orice_buget_233=1&toate_216=1&toate_196=1&toate_191=1&toate_211=1&orice_buget_190=1&toate_246=1&toate_244=1&toate_245=1&toate_247=1&orice_buget_243=1&toate_261=1&toate_259=1&toate_260=1&toate_262=1&orice_buget_258=1&toate_281=1&toate_279=1&toate_280=1&toate_282=1&orice_buget_278=1&toate_294=1&toate_292=1&toate_293=1&toate_295=1&orice_buget_291=1
```

**should return**

```
https://www.website.com/magazin/?orderby=price&product_category=tipuri-saltele&dimensiune_saltea=160x190-ro&stock_status=in-stock%2Con-backorder&min_price=30&max_price=9000&lang
```

**but it doesn't. It returns #VALUE!**

Any idea what I could do to make this work?

I suspect it's probably because the long and complex URL that it doesn't know how to compute it...

Thanks!

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/how-to-correct-a-value-error-in-the-vlookup-function-1fabc766-32ae-4f7f-a2c4-d095153e6894

Comment: Show input data to `Column A` then explain logic how your result will come?

Comment: @Harun24HR The input data in column A is the urls shown in the question. The result is the corresponding value from the column B on Sheet1. This would be clear for you if you read [how vlookup works](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vlookup-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1).

Comment: @GSerg - that idea actually worked. Instead of Vlookup I used index and match and it worked. The problem was the length of the cell content, not the fact that it was a weird URL. Thanks!